# How to get Primary Key and data from Django SessionWizardView

Tags: django, django-formwizard, django-formtools

I have a `SessionWizardView` that generate 3 forms, depending of of a previous choice. After the selection of the form, the user fill the form and submit it to a specific `ListView` to each case, using POST. The problem are to get these values, mainly the Primary Key.

The `SessionWizardView`, I followed the documentation (https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/wizard.html#wizard-template-for-each-form) and it's working as I expected. The 3 forms has the last field pre filled, depending from the first field.

In the `ListView`, I've tried to use `request.session.pop()` to get the fields from the `SessionWizardView`. Here I had my first doubt: I used either the variable name in the `forms.py`  (e.g.:`request.session.pop('formField1', {})`), and the field id in the POST (`request.session.pop('opcao1-formField1', {})`). In both cases the browser return the `'int' object has no attribute 'pk'` error.

I've tested the 3 forms that the Wizard can show me and all of them show the same error, so I will put the code for the first one, so text stay short.

urls.py:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

urlpatterns = [
    # path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(views.FORMS), name="index"),
    path('detail/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
```

views.py:

```
class IndexView(SessionWizardView):
    condition_dict = {"opcao1" :  graficoEscolhido1,
    "opcao2" :  graficoEscolhido2,
    "opcao3" :  graficoEscolhido3,
    }
    template_name = 'solid/index.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('detail')


    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        self.request.session['opcao1-dateDataInicial'] = str(form_list.cleaned_data['opcao1-dateDataInicial'])
        self.request.session['opcao1-dateDataFinal'] = str(form_list.cleaned_data['opcao1-dateDataFinal'])
        self.request.session['opcao1-codigoDuto'] = form_list.cleaned_data['opcao1-codigoDuto']
        self.request.session['opcao1-codigoExtremidade'] = float(form_list.cleaned_data['opcao1-codigoExtremidade'])
        # I've already commented the previous line, trade wizard for 
        # request. Put form_list.get_all_cleaned_data(), too as test.
        return render(self.request, "solid/detail.html", {
            'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
        })

class DetailView(generic.ListView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        # Trying to get from previous session. I've replaced request for 
        # wizard too, in previous attempt.
        inicio = self.request.session.pop('opcao1-dateDataInicial', {})
        final = self.request.session.pop('opcao1-dateDataFinal', {})
        cod_id = self.request.session.pop('opcao1-codigoID', {})
        extra = self.request.session.pop('opcao1-valorExtra', {})

        Temp1 = TEMP.objects.values_list('TE_CD_ID_S_Temp', flat = True).filter(
            TE_CD_ID_Cod = cod_id,
            TE_VL_Ponto = extra)

        Dens1 = DENS.objects.values_list('DE_CD_ID_S_Den', flat = True).filter(
            DE_CD_ID_Cod = cod_id,
            DE_VL_Ponto = extra)

        Vaz1 = VAZ.objects.values_list('VA_CD_ID_S_Vaz', flat = True).filter(
            VA_CD_ID_Cod = cod_id,
            VA_VL_Ponto = extra)

        Pres1 = PRES.objects.values_list('PR_CD_ID_S_Pres', flat = True).filter(
            PR_CD_ID_Cod = cod_id,
            PR_VL_Ponto = extra)        

        cursor.execute('giant query',(str(sensorPres[0]), inicio, final, 
                        str(sensorTemp[0]), inicio, final, 
                        str(sensorDens[0]), inicio, final, 
                        str(sensorVaz[0]), inicio, final))

        lista = cursor.fetchall()
        listaArray = np.asarray(lista)
        tempo = listaArray[:,0]

        valpres = listaArray[:,1]
        valpres = np.array(valpres)
        valpres = valpres.astype(float)

        valtemp = listaArray[:,2]
        valtemp = np.array(valtemp)
        valtemp = valtemp.astype(float)

        valden = listaArray[:,3]
        valden = np.array(valden)
        valden = valden.astype(float)

        valvaz = listaArray[:,4]
        valvaz = np.array(valvaz)
        valvaz = valvaz.astype(float)

        kwargs['tempo'] = tempo
        kwargs['valpres'] = valpres
        kwargs['valtemp'] = valtemp
        kwargs['valden'] = valden
        kwargs['valvaz'] = valvaz
        kwargs['dateInicial'] = inicio
        kwargs['dateFinal'] = final

        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

forms.py:

```
class get_Codigo_DutoGrafico1(forms.Form):
# codigoID is a PK in the model.
    codigoID = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label = "Código ID",        
        queryset = PRINCIPAL.objects.values_list('CD_ID', flat = True),
        widget = forms.SelectMultiple(attrs = {'id' : 'id_codigo_id'}))
    dateDataInicial = forms.DateTimeField(label = 'Data Inicial', 
        input_formats = ['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'], 
        widget=XDSoftDateTimePickerInput())
    dateDataFinal = forms.DateTimeField(label = 'Data Final',
        input_formats = ['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'],
        widget=XDSoftDateTimePickerInput())
    valorExtra = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label = 'Valor Extra',
        queryset = DENS.objects.values_list('DE_VL_Ponto', flat = True).none(),
        widget = forms.SelectMultiple(attrs = {'id' : 'id_codigoDropDown'}))
```

index.html:

```
<div class = "container-fluid" id = "wrapper">
    <div class = "row">
        {% load i18n %}
        {% block head %}
        {{ wizard.form.media }}
        {% endblock %}
      {% block content %}
      <p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
      <form action = "" method = "post" id = "formGrafico"  data-data-url="{% url 'ajax_load_duto' %}" data-data2-url="{% url 'ajax_load_data2' %}" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
      <table>
      {{ wizard.management_form }}
      {% if wizard.form.forms %}
          {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
          {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
              {{ form }}
          {% endfor %}
      {% else %}
          {{ wizard.form }}
      {% endif %}
      </table>
      {% if wizard.steps.prev %}
        <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">{% trans "first step" %}</button>
        <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans "prev step" %}</button>
      {% endif %}
      <input type="submit" value="{% trans "submit" %}"/>
      </form>
      {% endblock %}
```

I expect to get the values in the detail.html and show the data in different ways. However, I get the following error: 'int' object has no attribute 'pk'. The POST is returning the following:

```
POST
Variable    Value
csrfmiddlewaretoken 
'TArU7O0laFVnRiWp9rEpUOE4bUoPNYulB2zNkFbwnLFxbVBwr4Qmp7ZQ5FfhJ3r7'
index_view-current_step 
'opcao1'
opcao1-codigoDuto   
'177'
opcao1-dateDataInicial  
'03/05/2018 10:19:00'
opcao1-dateDataFinal    
'01/07/2018 10:20:00'
opcao1-codigoExtremidade    
'2,127000000000000'
```

The entire error traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 2.1.7
Python Version: 3.6.7
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'compressor',
 'django_extensions',
 'solid',
 'sekizai',
 'formtools']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/luiz/Projeto/Solid/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/luiz/Projeto/Solid/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/luiz/Projeto/Solid/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/luiz/Projeto/Solid/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/luiz/Projeto/Solid/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/formtools/wizard/views.py" in dispatch
  248.         response = super(WizardView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/luiz/Projeto/Solid/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/luiz/Projeto/Solid/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/formtools/wizard/views.py" in post
  301.         if form.is_valid():

File "/home/luiz/Projeto/Solid/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  185.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "/home/luiz/Projeto/Solid/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  180.             self.full_clean()

File "/home/luiz/Projeto/Solid/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  381.         self._clean_fields()

File "/home/luiz/Projeto/Solid/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_fields
  399.                     value = field.clean(value)

File "/home/luiz/Projeto/Solid/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in clean
  1293.         qs = self._check_values(value)

File "/home/luiz/Projeto/Solid/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _check_values
  1326.         pks = {str(getattr(o, key)) for o in qs}

File "/home/luiz/Projeto/Solid/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in <setcomp>
  1326.         pks = {str(getattr(o, key)) for o in qs}

Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: 'int' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

So the data is passing from SessionWizardView, but something in the middle is wrong. To test the 'int' problem, I've set str() to the "cod_id" and still got 'int' error message. I've searched in the Stack something related to it, but I found nothing.

Comment: I don't understand. When you POST the form, it's processed by your `IndexView` and runs the `done()` method. There you `return render()`, which should take the `request`, a template and a context. Not sure why you don't get a template not found error since you pass `self.success_url` instead of a template name here. Nowhere are you calling your `ListView` (you would need to `redirect` to that view)

Comment: Note that after `done()` the `WizardView` will delete the session data. So you should save the data from the submitted forms to the database (or to the session) if you want to use it in the next view you redirect to.

Comment: @dirkgroten after posted it, I passed `form_list.cleaned_data` to `request.session`, put the html link in the `render()` and still get the same error. I will update the question with these alterations.

Comment: when you have an error trace, please show the entire error trace, not just a summary of the error. It's not clear on which line of your code this error happens.

Comment: @dirkgroten sorry, just updated with the entire error trace back. The problem is that the error isn't in some line I wrote specifically. It's inner django/python, so I'm not knowing how to handle it. Just like I said in the end, I receive the PK field between a ```str()``` and still get the int error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @dirkgroten you comment redirect to the next view (```DetailView```), how I do this? I thought it would be done by the urls.py.

Comment: In your `done()` function you should `return redirect("detail")`. When you write `return render()` you're telling the template processor to render a template and send this HTML back to the browser as response. That has nothing to do with url patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because your `ModelMultipleChoiceField` has a `queryset` attribute set to an integer list, that's wrong, your queryset should be a list of objects: `PRINCIPAL.objects.all()`. The `ModelMultipleChoiceField` receives an integer as input (the posted data), but wants an object (`PRINCIPAL`) as `value`.

If you want to customise how the values are displayed to the user, you should subclass `ModelMultipleChoiceField` and override the `label_from_instance` method:

```
class IDModelMultipleChoiceField(ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, instance):
        return instance.pk
```

and in your form

```
cogidoID = IDModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=..., label=...)
```

Comment: But I need my form to show only this field, so I put values_list to the column that I want. How to overcome it?

Comment: by default the `ModelMultipleChoiceField` will show the result of the models' `__str__()` method as a display value (the one the user sees). You mean you want to actually display the `id` to the user? Then subclass `ModelMultipleChoiceField` and override the `label_from_instance()` method to just return the `id`.

Comment: I've used your suggestion to put ```object.all()``` and the error is gone, now my problem is the validation of the ```valorExtra```. I did a ```clean_valorExtra()``` setting it to float, but it's not working. I think it is because it is set as DECIMAL in the models.py. I will try set as decimal in python.

Comment: I've change for a ```ChoiceField``` and get de value in the ```_init_``` using ```self.data[]```. And it worked, but your solution skipped the first problem and helped me figure out the problem. I will put it as solved, thanks =)